Adding an input field to the active bar in vscode
I'm currently writing an extension for Visual Studio Code and have encountered a problem. I need the extension window that opens with the active bar to have an input field. In this case, the meaning should be retained in long-term memory. chatGPT produces non-working code, and the official docs don’t say anything about this (It’s just instructions for displaying the extension in the active bar)
example
At the moment I have the code that produced chatGPT. It contains a huge piece of html code, but specifically when you click on the extension icon it produces this: There is no data provider registered that can provide view data.
